# Spring JPA @Transactional Atomic

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

Using Hibernate JPA and Spring `@Transactional` (with Atomikos JTA implementation) I have the following Entities in my system:

- Order
- Orderline (holds a reference to the order)
- Customer

In a Service class method `addOrder` annotated with `@Transactional` I want to perform the following steps, in one transaction (it's one atomic function block).

1. Persist the Order
2. Persist the Orderlines
3. Persist the Customer

**At step 1** (persisting the Order) I want JPA to rollback on any `Exception`.

**At step 2** (persisting the Orderlines) I want to ignore any errors during the persisting of an orderline. So if I have 10 orderlines and 1 fails for any reason (constraint violation for example) I want to continue with the others.

**At step 3** In case of any `Exception` I want JPA to rollback the entire transaction, so also everything that was done in step 1 and 2.

Problems I ran into, so far:

- JPA marks the transaction as 'rollback only' in case of an `Exception`. So everything after (and before) this is rolled back, but I want to ignore the `Exception` at step 2.
- JPA only knows about the constraint violation after a `flush()` or `commit()` is called, which is usually after the `@Transactional` method is finished. I would need to know it inside my method.
- Tried to split each step in a separate `@Transactional` method, but since they need to use the same `Transaction` this doesn't change the previous two issues.

What is the best approach for this?

**Update**

Should I put all validation in Java and manually check if a record already exists for example?

Answer (score 1):

Put the second part in a `try-catch` block. For ex: The method body would probably look like this.

```
save(order);
flush();
for(Orderline line : orderlines) {
    try {
        orderlineService.save(line); 
        flush();   
    } catch(RuntimeException rte) {
        continue;
    }
}
save(customer);
```

Comment: @Bhasit in this case I run into problem 2 mentioned above. A constraint violation (entity already exists for example) might only be noticed when a commit is done. This commit is done only at the end of the main service, because that is the end of the transaction.

Comment: You want to ignore condtraint-violations? Also, which transaction-manager are you using?

Comment: Basically I would like to be abled to ignore any (Runtime)Exception that is caused by persisting the Orderline. We are using Atomikos.

Comment: Well, put a `flush` after persisting the `order` and after each `save` call on the `orderline`.

Comment: Or, since you don't care about constraint-violations on the `orderlines`, remove database-level constraints from its table. Then the code would work as you expect, without the `flush()` calls.  Since there are no constraints on the `orderlines` table, there shouldn't be any exception because of the constraint-violations after the transaction commits. If there is a constraint-violation on any of the other tables, the transaction would be rolled back, as you expect it to.

Comment: It's not that I don't care about the constraints. I definitely want them to be there. I just want to ignor a failure because of the constraint, but I don't want inconsistent data in my database of course. Maybe I should do all the validation in Java as well?

Comment: I am not sure. Depends on what you are planning to do. I wouldn't recommend it though, I mean, what you would be doing is essentially moving the constraint-checking from the database to the application level. Now, what are you planning to do if you find one of those constraints to be failing on `orderlines`? If you are planning to abort the transaction, the question itself becomes moot. I mean, it would be the same as your transaction-manager throwing the exception when it finds those constraint-violations.

Comment: Well the transactionmanager invalidates the transaction, which results in a rollback of the entire transaction. If I would find a constraint to be failing I could simply skip that particular ´orderline´ and continue with the next, while the transaction is still valid. I wonder if my example is really that special that there are no clear solutions :). With plain jdbc this is very easy to do.

Comment: I guess `flush` should solve your problem then. I mean, if you perform checks at the application level, that's what you might end up up doing anyway (even with plain-vanilla `JDBC`). Better let the database and the transaction-manager do the job (My Opinion).

Comment: I tried flush, and as it detects the constraint violation (which I want), it also marks the transaction as 'rollback only', so it invalidates the transaction. Not sure if that's caused by Atomikos, or by any transactionmanager. Going to test that now.

Comment: If the `orderlines` save method is executed in a separate `service` class, can you mark its `@Transactional` with `propagation` value of `NESTED` or `REQUIRES_NEW`? (if your transaction-manager supports these values.) I haven't tried that out, but that might just work.

Comment: ´REQUIRES_NEW´ would break the atomicity, because it starts a new independent transaction. ´NESTED´ would do what I need, but is not supported by standard JPA.

Comment: Okay, I have run out of options :).

Answer (score 0):

> **At step 2** (persisting the Orderlines) I want to ignore any errors
>   during the persisting of an orderline. So if I have 10 orderlines and
>   1 fails for any reason (constraint violation for example) I want to
>   continue with the others.

@Transactional is by default REQUIRED. Each method invocationg joins the current Transaction making all 3 operations atomic.

But in this case you should create a reentrant method using REQUIRES_NEW, indicating a new transaction for persisting each Orderline:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void persistMyOrderLine(OrderLine o) throws Exception{}
```

because failures persisting an orderline should not impact on another, a new transaction must be created for each one. So, aborting the TransactionA-OrderLineA does not impacts on TransactionB-OrderlineB.

**The problem is**: with your needs, by nature, the operation is not ATOMIC anymore. Because you have a scenario that a failure (orderline) is ignored, the operation is not ATOMIC and will not abort the role process (3 steps).

Maybe you should review these needs.

Comment: with this setup I get issues with step 3. If anything goes wrong with this I would need to rollback. But since the orderlines are already committed in a separate transaction (because of Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) I cannot rollback these orderlines. And beside that, the Orderline has a reference to the Order, which is in an uncommitted transaction. So I would get a referential integrity constraint violation I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order necessary?  Can Step 2 become Step 3?

If so, put steps 1 & 3 into a single transaction, and each individual `persist Orderline` into it's own transaction to be run afterwards.  Of course, this won't work if you need to rollback if *all* Orderlines fail to persist...

Another approach may be to create an *unmanaged* EntityManager for working with your `Orderline` entities; start transactions, catch exception, and manage commit/rollback on your own for them.

Ideally you'd use a *nested* transaction, which [JPA / JTA doesn't directly support](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions).  You can have some semblance by making the outer transaction's commit/rollback dependent on the inner transactions success/failure - or ignore (in your case) the inner transaction.

"Atomicity" tends to be a relative beast in practice - dependent much on the strength of your "transaction isolation" and chosen "locking level" (optimistic or pessimistic w/ variations).

My initial thoughts on this is that if you approached this like a thread-synchronization problem, and maintained some consistency on the order of nesting ('outer' always dealing with X, and 'inner' always dealing with 'Y') - you should be OK because the *serialized order* in which changes are applied would remain consistent.

Comment: your first approach would work in this particular situation. But I could image I had another set of entities that I want to persist and ignore exceptions for it. Then I would have the same issue again. About the other approach, that would be a completely different transaction then, so it would break my atomicity, isn't it?

Comment: If you ignore exceptions of some entities, is it still transactional? It would fail the C of ACID. I wonder it a solution would work with savepoints, but yeah, JPA doesn't play well with that.

Comment: @Luciano - if it's C according to user's requirements/code...  The point of ACID is to ensure that the system doesn't spring any surprises on you.